# Ignore folders in git but not the files in them

Tags: git, gitignore

I have created a Java project with IntelliJ. The project structure looks like:

```
rootfolder\projectname\src\*.java
```

And I would like to upload my Java classes to GitHub, but without `src` folder, like this:

```
rootfolder\projectname\*.java
```

Comment: Put the files in `project/a` — AFAIK, you can't have Git ignore a component of the path, which seems to be what you want.  There's room to suspect you have an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) — what are you really trying to achieve, and why do you think this might be a possible solution?

Comment: What do you mean ignore folders but track the files inside them? That doesn't make any sense to me. If it's tracking the files, what exactly is being ignored?

Comment: Are you sure you want to upload class files and *not* source files? That's the opposite of standard practice. Normally developers use version control for their source code and ignore `.class` files.

Comment: Sorry. I would like to upload the *.java files

Answer (score 1):

```
project/a/src/*
!project/a/src/files
```

Ignoring a directory is a summary execution, git's auto-add never even scans an ignored directory's contents (which is kind of the point of ignoring a directory, build systems can spew an astonishing amount of junk), so to ignore everything in a directory except a few things, you ignore everything in that directory except those few things, you don't ignore the entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your .gitignore (at the root of your project)

You can add :

`project/a/*/`

Note that the last slash means it's a directory and is therefore important to keep